# Tensorflow: feed_dict placeholder is Operation not Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a graph created in a python class. The initialiser enables me to either create a new graph,or load an existing graph.

If I initialise by creation, I create an input placeholder:

```
self.input = tf.placeholder("float", [None, self.input_size], name="x"
```

I can then save my graph:

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        self.sess, path, inputs={"x": self.input}, outputs={"encoded": self.encoded
```

If I initialize from a load, I first load the graph

```
tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        self.sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], path
    )
```

Then set my input and output names in the class

```
self.input = self.sess.graph.get_operation_by_name("x")
self.encoded = self.sess.graph.get_operation_by_name("encoded")
```

However, when I try and use my loaded graph, I get an error:

```
def encode(self, X):
    return self.sess.run(self.encoded, 
                         feed_dict={self.input: X})


==> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a Operation into a Tensor.
```

My feed_dict self.input is being interpreted as an operation, not a tensor. Note that I can't load "x" as a tensor - if I try `self.input = self.sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("x")`, I get an error, reporting that "x" is the name of an operation, not a tensor.

However, if I examine self.input, it is reported as being a placeholder:

```
name: "x"
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 81
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying a whole op, but since ops can have more than one output you have to tell exactly which output you want. Try this:

```
def encode(self, X):
    return self.sess.run(self.encoded, 
                         feed_dict={self.input.outputs[0]: X})
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
self.input = self.sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
```